# How does a Ruby gem becomes invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ssl-certificate

My Ruby on Rails dev server has been running for a while on Windows 2016 server. But I had to restart it yesterday.

Then it raised the following error:

```
The git source https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

I don't understand where this suddenly comes from !?! I created this gem 2 years ago by forking an obsolete version from DatozMX/write_xlsx_rails. And it used to work as expected. It is declared in Gemfile as the following:

```
# XLSX format support
gem 'write_xlsx'
gem 'write_xlsx_rails', git: 'https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git', branch: 'master'
```

If I replace the remote reference by the former local path (used when updating the gem), the gem is made available. But this cannot be used for deployment.

So I tried to run bundle install as suggested, and I get the following error:

```
Retrying `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet --no-tags --depth 1 --single-branch --branch master -- https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git 
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/write_xlsx_rails-858752332ce805e34a469f55ad6a2b115033800a` at C:/Sites/sis-portal due to error (2/4): 
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet --no-tags --depth 1 --single-branch --branch master -- https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git 
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/write_xlsx_rails-858752332ce805e34a469f55ad6a2b115033800a` in directory C:/Sites/sis-portal has failed.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fchampreux/write_xlsx_rails.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

As other gems are correctly updated by the Bundler, I suspect a certificate issue. But why only on  this gem from my GitHub repository? This is beyond my competency!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by updating Git.

We use the SSL version built into Git install. We installed it more than 2 years ago ... and its certificates were over 2 years old and had expired.